# Get website title back from Android browser?

Tags: java, android

My Android application launches the system default web browser to display a URL to the user.   I want to capture the title of this URL so I can save it in my own app history.  I know I can do this if I use a WebView, but I feel like the user experience would be  much better if the user could use their preferred browser instead of an in-app one.  After reading many similar questions on this site, I'm feeling like this can't be done and I will have to use an in-app browser or scrape the page myself to get the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, **you can't** get the data back from the android default browser, If you want to do any interfacing with browser like getting url, runnig java script, you have to use your application's webview.